# Remove specific query from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to remove specific query string from URL?

I have here any really old directory that I have cleaned up, put into a new Script, transfered everything and hey, it looks now fine again and yeah, its what I wanted. But when i checked for old Links and Pages, i found some last remaining garbage like this:

http://www.domain.tld/index.php?page=1&cat=18&u_sort=uptime&u_order=asc

http://www.domain.tld/index.php?cat=45

So i have tried to get rid of them via htaccess and the removal of Query strings

Tryout 1 -- Pretty, but no more possible to add new Links via Form, changed to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\?
RewriteRule (.*) /? [R=301,L]
```

Tryout 2 -- Pretty too, got into adding a link, but next windown not working, as it added a query string normally and that gets removed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\?
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

So now the idea would be to simply remove only these two query strings and let everything else untouched. How to do so?

http://www.domain.tld/index.php?page=1&cat=18&u_sort=uptime&u_order=asc
and
http://www.domain.tld/index.php?cat=45

should be simply

http://www.domain.tld/

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?cat=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^&]+)&cat=([^&]+)&u_sort=([^&]+)&u_order=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [NC,L,R]
```

this will redirect :

```
 http://example.com/index.php?cat=foo
```

or

```
 http://example.com/index.php?page=123&cat=foo&u_sort=bar&u_order=foo
```

to

```
http://example.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll give it a try!